# Не получается через CURL получить картинки с Google Images

Tags: php, curl, google-images

Идея следующая: по ключевому слову какое я дам, curl должен находить картинки в Google Images, потом я хочу найти нужный div, в котором лежат все эти картинки и через PHPQuery получить ссылки на все эти картинки. В коде я прописываю, что мне надо искать

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/search?q=Steve&tbm=isch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36');
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($out);
```

В случае, если я введу echo $document, то мне спарсится всё со страницы. Но когда я делаю вот так:

```
$imgs = $document->find('img');
```

и вывожу это всё дело, то получается вот такое. Куда пропадают src теги? Почему картинки не выводятся? Что нужно сделать? Бьюсь уже много времени и действительно в ступоре.

[image: получается вот такое]

Comment: у тега <img> в src нет обычного url, там строка вида `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA..<и далее набор символов, описывающих превью изображения в base64>`. Сдаётся мне, не там вы ищите сурсы для ваших изображений =/ а вот родительский тег <a> в href уже содержит кое-что похожее на ссылку на изображение, правда начиная с "imgurl=" и далее идёт url немного закодированный

Comment: Действительно, спасибо. А как тут быть в таком случае? Обновлено: прочитал, спасибо